# How to label table cells and create the formula for a summation?

Tags: summation, notation

I want to label each cell in a table and then
create the formula of a summation over each column.

I'm new to math and not really sure if my syntax is correct. Espacially the labeling over 3 layers like $c_{x_t}$ and the labeling of the cells like $E_{c_1,t_2}$. Can I label it like that?

Example:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
c_x & t_1 & t_2 & t_n \\
\hline
c_1 & E_{c_1,t_1} & E_{c_1,t_2} & E_{c_1,t_n} \\
c_2 & E_{c_2,t_1} & E_{c_2,t_2} & E_{c_2,t_n} \\
c_n & E_{c_n,t_1} & E_{c_n,t_2} & E_{c_n,t_n} \\
SUM & S(t_1;c_1;c_n) & S(t_2;c_1;c_n) & S(t_n;c_1;c_n)
\end{array}
$$

Get SUM **f**rom the column $t_1$ over $c_1$ **t**o $c_n$:

$St(t_x;c_{x_f};c_{x_t}) = \sum_{k=c_{x_f}}^{c_{x_t}} E(c_k;t_x)$

Thanks alot!

Comment: It is necessary, that you define the variables and the indices. This is really important. Then a simplification is possible.

Comment: Do you mean with define to  declare the domain like {x ∈ N|x>5} or the meaning of the variables?

Comment: The meaning of the variables and indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You notation is unclean in a way: You actually want the sum to be
$$S(t_1;c_1;c_n) := \sum_{k=1}^n E_{c_k, t_1}$$

The problem here is how are you going to assure that given *the value of* $c_1$ and $c_n$, you know from where to where to sum?
In other words, if $c_1, \ldots, c_n = 1, \ldots, 1$ then what is $S(t_1;1;1)$?

Is it $\sum_{k=1}^1 E_{c_k,t_1} = E_{c_1, t_1} = E_{1,t_1}$ or is it $\sum_{k=1}^n E_{c_k,t_1} = n E_{1, t_1}$? Or even some other sub-summation?

A clean approach would be instead to tell $S$ about the *indices* to sum from and to:

$$S(t;i_1;i_2) := \sum_{k=i_1}^{i_2} E_{c_k,t}$$

This prevents any ambiguity in the notation.

Comment: Ok, thats looks great. Maybe I thought too complicated. And it's ok to label  the cells like this or do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve and what the context is. If you were tabulating nutritional value of different types of cookies and for some reason wanted to sum them, that would be a very unfortunate notation ^^

Comment: I want to build an evaluation matrix. The table above is just a part of the whole. And with the variables, indices and functions I want to show how each cell is calculated. A theoretically overview of each cell and how it is defined.